# Relational style query against Neo4j graph database

Tags: database, neo4j

I am new to neo4j database. I was looking for graph based database and found neo4j interesting. I wanted to know if it is possible to query neo4j database in Relational database style. Let me explain myself with an example:

I have a graph database of all students in class. Nodes contain student information and the relationships are 'friendship'. Each node has properties like name of student, class and cgpa. Now I want to get list of all students whose cgpa > 4. Is it possible to do this in neo4j in single query? Or do I need to find all nodes and then manipulate them?

It would also be very helpful if anyone can point out some good resource for neo4j queries.

Answer (score 2):

I always worked with the [Neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/).
If you are using Spring Data Neo4j, the free book [Good Relationships](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf) may also help.

There is a query language called [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-query-lang.html). There are even some examples in the documentation which may fit pretty good to your case [[1]](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html):

```
start n=(2, 1) where n.age < 30 return n
```

This one starts on the given nodes with id 2 and 1 and returns them if their age property is below 30. `start n=(*)` would do it for every node. You should read the whole specifications.

Depending on what you do and how you want to find specific nodes, you can use [indices](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html).

However, you should not use a graph database the same way as a relational one. For your described scenario it might be ok, but try to design the relations in a way that you can use them later on for your traversals. It is much faster.